# Is there something like DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory for creating an async client?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, mqtt, paho

I would like to use an async Paho client in Spring Integration:

```
@Bean
public DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory clientFactory() {
    return new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
}

<int-mqtt:message-driven-channel-adapter id="mqttInbound"
client-id="${mqtt.default.client.id}.src"
url="${mqtt.url}"
topics="sometopic"
client-factory="clientFactory"
channel="output"/>
```

Do I have to write one on my own? I can only find examples for sync client factories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct; at this time, only the sync client is supported.

Feel free to open an [improvement JIRA issue here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) and, of course [contributions are always welcome - guidelines here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

That said, it's not clear to me the benefit of using an async client in the inbound adapter as in your example; it is message-driven and arriving messages are delivered asynchronously on the client's thread. Obviously, the outbound adapter could gain some benefit from async operations.

The [outbound adapter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-mqtt/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/mqtt/outbound/MqttPahoMessageHandler.java) is pretty simple and shouldn't be too hard to write one that uses the async client - it would probably need to send the delivery tokens to some channel - but we should abstract away from the `IMqttDeliveryToken` object so we don't leak `Paho` into the upper layers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory() provided by Spring Integration is using the "synchronous" mode of operation in Paho, so the likelihood is that you would need an alternative ClientFactory implementation.

Comment: Yup. I don't mind writing my own factory per se, but the question is: What interface must it be compliant to? The default factory returns an MqttClient, so if the Spring Integration MQTT inbound channel adapter ONLY accepts/expects an MqttClient (and not an MqttAsyncClient) to be returned, I would be standing in front of closed doors? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Correct - I added another answer because comments are limited in length.